# UINavigationControoller - setNavigationBarHidden:animated: How to sync other animations

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

How can I capture the animation curve and speed when I hide the navigation bar programmatically?  I would like to sync other animations with this one for a fluid transition :)

Comment: are you using caanimation for other animations on the same screen?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you check the UINavigationController documentation there is this line:

> For animated transitions, the duration of the animation is specified by the value in the `UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration` constant.

Answer (score 14):

Below is a code snippet for those who would like to take the advice of the accepted answer, but don't know how to go about it :)

```
 [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
 [UIView transitionWithView:self.view 
                   duration:UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^
  {
   /* Put other animation code here ;) */
  }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) 
  {                                  
  }];
```

Comment: Not sure about previous versions but in iOS 8 and 9 its UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut, not Linear.