# Making the app wait a few seconds before executing code?

Tags: ios

Im trying to implement a way of taking a screenshot in my application. I want the UINavigationBar tip slide up - take the screenshot - and then the UINavigationBar can slide down nice and easy. I need the app to wait/hold a few seconds between some lines of code, because this  way the first animation does not get time to finish:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES ];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

So, is there a way of delaying execution, like when animation a button like so:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{self.myButton.frame = someButtonFrane;} completion:nil];
```

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(hideShowBarButton) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

and of course:

```
- (void) hideShowBarButton{
    if (self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden)
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES ];
    else
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES ];
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use:

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0; // number of seconds to wait
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    /***********************
     * Your code goes here *
     ***********************/
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While there doesn't appear to be a callback for `setNavigationBarHidden`'s completion, it will take `UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration` seconds. So just use a `NSTimer` to delay it:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration target:self selector:@selector(myFunction:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

You may want to add a small amount to the delay as a fail-safe;

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration+0.05 target:self selector:@selector(myFunction:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

See also this related question: [UINavigationControoller - setNavigationBarHidden:animated: How to sync other animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716339/uinavigationcontrooller-setnavigationbarhiddenanimated-how-to-sync-other-ani)